# Unable to start CompizConfig Settings Manager in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compiz

CompizConfig Settings Manager is unable to start in my Ubuntu 16.04. I ran `ccsm` in Terminal, and it gave me the following error message:

```
$ ccsm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ccsm", line 94, in <module>
    import ccm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ccm.Window import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Window.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ccm.Pages import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Pages.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ccm.Settings import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Settings.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ccm.Widgets import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ccm/Widgets.py", line 32, in <module>
    mimetypes.init()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py", line 358, in init
    db.read(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetypes.py", line 202, in read
    with open(filename) as fp:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types'
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster `-rw------ 1 root root` Why is it not allowed to be read by me?

Comment: Seems this package hasn't been touched since 12.04
https://launchpad.net/compizconfig-settings-manager/+packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason there are files in `/usr/local/lib` that are not world-readable. This is probably a mistake. To make all files in `/usr/local/lib` world-readable run:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Why are my files not world-readable in `/usr/local/lib`? Do you also have the same problem?

Comment: I don't know and no. The packages coming from Canonical's repositories never put anything into `/usr/local`. Most of the files there stem from manually installed packages (i. e. `make && sudo make install` or things like `sudo ./setup.sh`). Most likely the installation scripts were broken and/or you set `umask` to a non-standard value or you changed the permissions (more or less) wilfully.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run it with gksudo or if you do not have it, please search for CompizConfig then select it

Comment: Running with gksudo can start CompizConfig Settings Manager, but I guess it configures settings for root user not me? I changed some CompizConfig with gksudo, but the changes do not work.